# Cargo recompiles package in workspace with "-p" after compiling with "--workspace"

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

In general, I compile everything in my workspace with: `cargo build` from the workspace directory, or with `cargo build --workspace`

However, if I then compile a specific package with `cargo build -p package` or by running `cargo build` from that package's directory, it will recompile it, when actually it should be completely cached, right?

It seems that the things being rerun are mostly related to macros... recompiling `syn`, `serde_derive`, etc...

Is it somehow expected that these macro crates need to be recompiled because they might give different results? I feel like that really shouldn't be the case if we want reproducible builds!

What can I do to prevent cargo from recompiling like this?

(this is with cargo 1.51.0 on a raspberry pi 4 running Raspbian 10)

Comment: Does the package have a build script, perchance?

Comment: @eggyal That package doesn't, although there are other packages that do in the workspace. (but they didn't recompile here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen when different packages have different sets of features. When `cargo build --workspace` is run, the dependencies are built with union of the enabled features. When `-p package-name` is used, only the features needed by that package are used, resulting in recompilation of dependencies where some features are not turned on.

If I run `cargo build --bin package-name` instead, the number of recompiled crates is much lower although there still are a few.

There's a short discussion about this on the [Rust forums](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/avoiding-rebuilds-when-doing-cargo-build-package-x/89104).